# How can I change text in a div which has no id

Tags: jquery

How do I use jquery to change the text "This is the text to change"

```
<div class="MyDiv">
    <div>
        This is the text to change
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I got the example wrong it should be <div class="MyDiv">

Comment: Then use `.MyDiv > div` selector. Similar like my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `#MyDiv > div` selector like following.

```
$('#MyDiv > div').text('changed text');
```

Answer (score 1):

A general solution for any `div` w/o an id attribute could be

```
$("div:not[id]").html("Your message goes here");
```

This selector targets any `div` without an id attribute. For other elements, substitute `div` with whatever element you want.

Answer (score 0):

simply do like below,

```
$("div#MyDiv div").text("This is changed Text"); // in this line, it calls for the div inside the div which its id=MyDiv.
```

try below working demo, it shows how to change the text normally and , in a button click.hope this will help to you.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>


</style>

<body>
<div id="MyDiv">
    <div>This is the text to change
    </div>
    <button id="change">Change the text</button>
</div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("div#MyDiv div").text("This is changed Text"); // in this line, it calls for the div inside the div which its id=MyDiv.


//if you want to do it in button click
$("#change").click(function(){
    $("div#MyDiv div").text("I changed because of button clicked.");
});

</script>

</html>
```